# RavenDb: How to Get All Documents that have an related document?

Tags: ravendb, ravendb5

So I've looked at the samples which use LoadDocument, but that requires the Id of the document that you're loading. In my case it's the exact opposite. I need all of the primary documents that have a document related to it, for which I know the relationship in the related document based on the id of the primary document.

How do I write it?

I.e.

Primary = {Id, Name}
Secondary = {Id, Name, PrimaryId}

So I want to get all of the Primary for which a Secondary (with other criteria about the secondary) exists.

In linq I'd just use from p in session.Primary where session.Secondary.Any(s => s.PrimaryId && whateverElse) select p) but this doesn't work as it doesn't understand it.

I've tried to construct this as a manual index but I can't figure out how to create the link to the related document since LoadDocument only takes the ID of the related document, which from the primary document I don't have it.